# How to print a variable in html tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Why variable `a` is undefined?

```
export default function Surah() {
  let a;
  const toDo= (id) => {
    a = id;
    console.log(a);
  };

  return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => toDo(1)}></button>
          <div>{a}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
  )
}
```

Can you explain what is wrong with my code ?

Comment: Where do you call the `Tafsir()` function? `a` is not set until that point.

Comment: changing the variable value doesn't trigger the component to render again with updated value, for this updated value you need to render the component again using setState

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `a` as state variable.

changing the variable value doesn't trigger the component to render again with the updated value, for this updated value you need to render the component again using setState.

```
import {useState} from "react";

export default function Surah() {
  const [a, setA] = useState();
  const toDo= (id) => {
    setA(id);
  };

  return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => toDo(1)}>Click here</button>
          <div>{a}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: You don't specify button label.

Answer (score 1):

this is not an optimal way of using the variables. Instead we should `useState` hook. I'm attaching the code snippet below for your reference.

```js
import {useState} from "react";

export default function Surah() {
  const [a,setA] = useState(0); // Initialize it with a number
  const Tafsir = (id) => {
    setA(id);
  };

  return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => {
           Tafsir(1);
           console.log(a);
          }}>Click Here</button>
          <div>{a}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: answered already

Comment: @AbasahebGaware you both have answered it partially - just the solution to the code, there's the OP question of `Why variable a is undefined?` that you both missed to answer.

Comment: @Aleksandar below answer explains why a is undefined and I have added a comment also